# Is there guidance on when we should vote to delete posts?

Tags: discussion, moderation

So I recently triggered the 10k threshold and gained access to some moderator tools, but the only thing of real note seems to be the ability to cast Delete votes. Per the [moderator tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) guidance, it just says:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

...as well as some stuff about not deleting when good answers are present.

We've a ton of 'help me make a character' kind of questions that are scattered all over, which I think should be removed if just for the sake of minimizing them, but the definition of 'no lasting value,' is very broad such that I'm kind of iffy on deleting anything. I mean, there might be 2 people trying to create a vampire/werewolf hybrid homebrew race that's balanced, but also not terribly likely.

I assume the answer is going to be personal similar to the nature of voting, but is there a general preference for what should be and should not be deleted?

Comment: Is this question focusing on deleting questions, answers, or both? It seems most of the body is talking about questions, but I just wanted to be clear.

Comment: Note that the delete vote button doesn’t appear until a post is meaningfully rejected already (question closed for 48 hours; answers scored <= -3). And it’s a vote, not a direct delete. Does that change your question?

Comment: @HellSaint: Good find.

Answer (score 2):

It has to have no lasting value **whatsoever**. It must be of no value to anyone, not merely something so obscure that only one or two people would ever be interested in this question or its answer.

Things that I would delete:

- Spam
- Abusive comments
- Jibberish

Things I would not necessarily delete:

- Off-topic questions (if they can be moved to another Stack Exchange where that question would be on-topic)
- Downvoted answers (they may serve as good examples of wrong answers)

I would only delete things that **need to be deleted in order to improve the experience of the site's users**.