# Which option should I choose for bad but not-obviously-deletion-worthy posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Tags: support, review

The "Low Quality Posts" review queue presents me with four options for each post.  The guidance it provides on which one to pick is:

> - **Looks OK** if nothing is wrong with this answer
> - **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
> - **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

My impression based on questions like [this one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8201/is-there-guidance-on-when-we-should-vote-to-delete-posts) is that the threshold for when to delete a post is pretty high; involving phrases like "no lasting value whatsoever."  It's also telling that all of the built-in comments when you click the **Recommend Deletion** button are variants on not-an-answer.

Most of the time, the posts I see in this queue are bad, but not obviously so bad that they meet the stringent criteria for being expunged from the site; they're more the kind of thing that I would toss a downvote on, maybe a "this answer could be improved by..." comment if there isn't one there already, and move on.

But I'm not sure what that means in terms of the review queue:

> **Looks OK** if nothing is wrong with this answer

Not this one; there *is* something wrong with the answer, namely it's bad.

> **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer

Great option if I can fix all the problems, but frequently I can't.

> **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted

I think I'm only supposed to click this if it's egregiously terrible or not-an-answer, not if it's merely bad.

> **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

This is what I usually end up clicking, but doesn't this just kick the can down the road for the next reviewer?

Comment: Thanks for posting this--VLQ is one I have always had trouble with, too. (I think I've probably "skip"ped 80% of them.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

“Looks OK” is appropriate here. If in doubt, feel free to Skip and save your energy for posts you can more comfortably figure out.

Despite the wording, “Looks OK” is also fine for posts that might get downvoted or need additional info added by the author. It's OK as in this post isn't nonsense or spam or whatever, and that it can actually viably survive on the site and doesn't need to be deleted. It might not be 100% OK, but that's fine, you're not vouching that it's awesome, just that it is OK *enough.*

Comment: This Meta is then probably an indication of a wording change being needed.